# Variable error when using track location on a map view

Tags: swift, geolocation, core-location

I am trying to show and track location on a map view. I am getting the error:

> Use of local Variable 'locationManager' before declaration

The error is on all lines of locationManager:

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

I have declared `var locationManager = CLLocationManager()` before `ViewDidLoad`.

Do I have my variables in the wrong place?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class InfoViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var infoImageView: UIImageView!


    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func urlButton(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    // Variables

    var gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

    var store: Store!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Background image
        self.infoImageView.image = UIImage(data: store.photo)

        // Set label text
        self.nameLabel.text = store.name

        // Set category text
        var categoryText = String()
        for category in store.storeCategories {
            if !categoryText.isEmpty {
                categoryText += ", "
            }
            categoryText += category.name
        }

        categoryLabel.text = categoryText




        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {

            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
            let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            }

        // Gesture recoginizer
        gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissView")
        self.gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.gesture)

    }

    func dismissView() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: Which line does that error appear on?  Would be helpful to show the whole file so we can see where `locationManager` is declared.

Comment: Thanks @NickEntin I am getting the error for all the location manager variables. I updated the code in the original question. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare locationManager outside a block, in this case, you've tried to declare it inside an `if-block` which will give make it a local variable. Declare the variable outside the `if-block.` Working sample code for the job:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
```

As you can see, I have declared the variable at the same level as the `viewDidLoad()` method, giving it a more larger scope.

And then, in your if-block you can do this:

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Note that I removed the first line for the `locationManager = CLLocationManager()` as it is already instantiated.

Also, the function for locationManager must not be inside the viewDidLoad method.

Moreover, I don't understand why your `if-block` is wrapping the method.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense to me now that I shouldn't have called the func locationManager in view did load. Appreciate you helping me understand. Map is working great :)

Comment: @amym Dude are you ever gonna tick an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Hassan said, all you need to do is move the `locationManager(...)` function declaration out of the if block. The important thing to realize is that in Swift, you can pass references to functions just like variables.  Therefore the declaration of the `locationManager(...)` function, which would be referred to as just `locationManager`, overrides the declaration of the variable.

Your code should now look like this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class InfoViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var infoImageView: UIImageView!


    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func urlButton(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    // Variables

    var gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

    var store: Store!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Background image
        self.infoImageView.image = UIImage(data: store.photo)

        // Set label text
        self.nameLabel.text = store.name

        // Set category text
        var categoryText = String()
        for category in store.storeCategories {
            if !categoryText.isEmpty {
                categoryText += ", "
            }
            categoryText += category.name
        }

        categoryLabel.text = categoryText

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {

            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        // Gesture recoginizer
        gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissView")
        self.gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.gesture)

    }

    func dismissView() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

}
```

In addition, when you set this object as the delegate, it expects the method to be directly accessible from the class.  Again, in Swift, methods are just like variables when it comes to scope.  So when you declare it inside another method, it is not accessible from the class.  When you declare it directly under the class, it can be accessed calling `delegate.locationManager(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Helped me get my head around it. Works great now. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Happy I could help :)